# Using string as search condition

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a search function that gets a result set of records based on one argument eg:

```
records = records.Where(x => x.DistrictId == model.DistrictId);
```

Now I am trying to return from multiple stations (stations are within districts).

```
var stationRecords = "";

if (model.Stations != null)
{
    if (model.Stations.Count() >= 1)
    {
        if (!model.Stations.Any(x => x == 0.ToString()))
        {
            foreach (var s in model.Stations)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stationRecords))
                    stationRecords = String.Format("records.Where(x => x.StationName.Equals({0}))", s);
                else
                    stationRecords += String.Format(" || records.Where(x => x.StationName.Equals({0}))", s);
            }
        }
    }
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stationRecords))
    records = stationRecords;
```

Records cannot convert from an `IQueryable<>` to a string but I need to pass a condition as a single argument. And I can't use it in the for loop as I'd be trying to search stations based on already searched stations. I want to search all the records where any of these stations exist. Stations is a string array of stations.

Comment: you might want to use `Expressions` in that case

Comment: This may be a silly question, but if you are comparing `x` to the hardcoded value of `0.ToString()`, why call `ToString()` over and over again?  Just do `x => x == "0"`

Comment: I should've used "0"..just an oversight on my part. 0 is inserted into the array after its populated as an equivalent to "All stations".

Comment: Obviously, StationId is an enumerable of something. What type is StationId? Please rename it to something that makes sense ("Stations"?).

Comment: Why not `List<string> ids = model.StationId.ToList();` then just `records = records.Where(x => ids.Any(id => x.StationName.Equals(id)));`?

Comment: Side note, you can just do `if (model.Stations != null && model.Stations.Count() => 1 && !model.Stations.Any(x => x == "0"))` and get the exact same effect but cleaner with less lines and indents